# Can we tell users that the Help Center is needed to be visited, not should

Tags: feature-request, help-center

A lot of new users don't have much idea about how to ask or answer here at Stack Exchange. Then we get complaints that we are too strict and we are anti-new-user or some other conspiracy made up. But the thing is, the tour says:

> Looking for more in-depth information about this site?

Clearly, this suggests that the Help Center is not necessary and everything in the tour is enough to ask a good question... ***NOT!*** Actually, comments directed to new users suggest that you are supposed to read the Help Center in the first place, so why not make the tour lead you in a path in which that it encourages you to read the important Help Center articles.

Let's do the following to all the tours:

- Put links into its respective section

For example, in the "Ask questions about..." section, add the link to the asking articles or the "How do I ask a good question" article. Especially for the voting section, where most users misinterpret how votes are used as downvotes are not explained and there is no Help Center link attached to help curious users learn about the voting system.

- Make the text next to the Help Center button more encouraging

Just change it to something like:

> Please read the Help Center articles to improve everyone's experience at this site

So, can we add Help Center links into the tour and encourage new users to read those articles so they don't get confused and frustrated?

Comment: Yep, that will solve all the problems, because they are certain to read and follow guidance, like they already do!

Comment: Are you being sarcastic?

Comment: Do you have to ask?

Comment: Yes yes I do because that comment is borderline for me

Comment: IMO people aren't going to do things just because you tell them to. Also, the people who should read  it are the least likely to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the language about reading the help center content could be changed.  On the other hand, it might be more effective to provide people with information and directions in the Stack Exchange flow at the points that the information is most relevant and actionable.  Or do both!  :)

Comment: This would be a much better answer (or perhaps even a separate question) by breaking down ideas for how to do just-in-time guidance that's not horribly long.